# Django aggregation

Tags: python, django

followprofile model:

```
class FollowProfile(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('userdata.Profile')
    following = models.ForeignKey('userdata.Profile', related_name='following')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('profile', 'following'),)

    [...]
```

profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    [...]
```

Example data what I want to get is below:

```
profile id 1 - followed by 10 profiles, following 3 profiles
profile id 2 - followed by 5 profiles, following 6 profiles
profile id 3 - followed by 2 profiles, following 1 profiles
profile id 4 - followed by 8 profiles, following 0 profiles
[...]
profile id 1204 - followed by 1 profiles, following 3 profiles
```

I know I could somehow try to use Django aggregation tools, so I tried:

```
>>> profiles = Profile.objects.annotate(num_follows=Count('followprofile')).order_by('-num_follows')[:3]
>>> for profile in pofiles:
...     profile.num_follows
...     profile.user.username
35
u'chica'
24
u'xxxxx'
11
u'yyyyy'
```

But this gives me numbers of followed profiles per profile. Equal to:

```
>>> FollowProfile.objects.filter(profile__user__username='chica').count()
35
```

I want also numbers of following profiles per person. Equal to:

```
>>> FollowProfile.objects.filter(following__user__username='chica').count()
11
```

How could I build my call to get that numbers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related name of field 'following' is `following`, so this should work:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.annotate(num_following=Count('following'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put the `annotate` call after the `values` call, it should count the number of `following` profiles per unique value of the values argument. Try this:

```
FollowProfile.objects.all().values('profile').annotate(num_followers=Count('following'))
```